# Bootstrap : how to make colspan including inner gutter

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I'm new to bootstrap and I'm trying to get familiar with the grid layout but I'm stuck on finding how to get an equivalent to "colspan" that would take in consideration the space between columns.

If you have a look on what i did here you'll see what I would like to do :

https://jsfiddle.net/1t1L0kh2/1/

My problem is that I want to get red containers a fixed sized (e.g. 100px) and the green one twice a red one plus the space between two containers, which may change since it's based on bootstrap's grid.

I managed to get the thing working with relative sizing :

https://jsfiddle.net/1t1L0kh2/2/

which is fine for green container, but I don't want the red ones to get resized.

Here is my initial code (fiddle 1) :

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="text-center">
        <ul class="my-items">
            <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2" >
                <div class="box"></div>
            </li>

            <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2" >
                <div class="box"></div>
            </li>

            <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2" >
                <div class="box"></div>
            </li>

            <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2" >
                <div class="box"></div>
            </li>

            <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2" >
                <div class="box"></div>
            </li>

            <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2" >
                <div class="box"></div>
            </li>

            <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2" >
                <div class="box"></div>
            </li>

            <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2" >
                <div class="box"></div>
            </li>

            <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <div class="lbox"></div>
            </li>

              <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2" >
                <div class="box"></div>
            </li>

              <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2" >
                <div class="box"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 10px;
}

.my-items {
    margin:0 0 0 0;
}

.my-items li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.box {
        background: #f00;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px
}

.lbox {
        background: #0f0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px
}
```

Do you have any idea on how I can realize that ?
Thanks

Comment: Using bootstrap cols and having a fixed size box is strange. You need to set the width of the parent container. So that `parent width / 6 = 200px`.

Comment: Maybe am I doing it wrong. In fact I said I wanted fixed size because I plan to add images here to make a gallery that would have that behaviour (http://www.templatemo.com/templates/templatemo_395_urbanic/#templatemo-portfolio) ; as you can see, image size does not change until a gap while the gutter between them reduces.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want. But to give the red boxes in your second fiddle a fixed size, why don't use just media queries? e.g. `@media (max-width: 768px) { 
.box {
    width: 100px;
}}` (https://jsfiddle.net/1t1L0kh2/4/). And I don't think the gutters in your example change between the gaps..